# Mahalanobis Distance in DBSCAN Clustering with R

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, distance, dbscan, mahalanobis

I have read the R documentation and some sources. As I understand it, the DBSCAN syntax in R automatically uses the Euclidean distance. For example like the following syntax:

`kNNdist(data, k = 3)`

`kNNdistplot(data, k = 3)`

`abline(v = 21)`

`abline(h = 2.079)`

`dbscan(data, eps = 2.079, MinPts = 3)`

What if I want to use Mahalanobis distance? Is it possible?

Comment: Yes, you can pass `dbscan` a `dist` object. If you can turn your `data` into a suitable `dist` object, then it should be fine. For Malahanobis you could perhaps cobble something together using `cor` and `as.dist`.